# NODE express route Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, express, routes, get

I created a connection node mysql using express.
so i have this error that i cannot understand where is wrong

"Cannot GET /" into my localhost http://localhost:8080/

and in the google error (white the F12) he show me this :

-"GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)"

-"DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hnmpcagpplmpfojmgmnngilcnanddlhb/browser-polyfill.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

ther i have the organization of my files;

```
-controllers
    user.controller.js
-routes
    user.routes.js
server.js
```

this is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
//const dbConfig = require("./config/db.config.js");

//à voir apres
//var routes = require('./routes/indexRoutes');

//configuration de express server
//parse requests of content-type - application/json
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
  };



// parse requests of content-type
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//connection à la bdd
const db = require("./models");



//on démarre le serveur
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log("Express serveur est opérationnelle sur le port : "+PORT);
});


require("./routes/user.routes")(app);
```

user.controller.js

```
const mysqlConnection = require("../models");

// afficher tout les users
exports.findAllUser = (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * From user', (err, rows, fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            console.log(rows);
            res.send(rows);
        }
        else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

user.routes.js

```
module.exports = userRoutes => {
    const userController = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");
    var router = require("express").Router();
  
    // Create a new Tutorial
    router.get("/", userController.findAllUser);
  
    userRoutes.use('/api/tutorials', router);
};
```

What are the reasons for this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Your code references both `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8081`. Is this a typo or are you just off a port.

Comment: Actually, not sure if this is your issue, but you define `corsOptions` after you use it with `app.use(cors(corsOptions));`.

Comment: don't know but didn't change anuthing

Answer (score 0):

You didn't parse the router to express.

In `user.routes.js` try

```
userRoutes.use('/api/tutorials', router);
```

and the api url should be `http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials`

Comment: yea i forgott ", router" because i've triyng something but forgott about it when a wis writting the question, but yea i totaly forgot the api url, that work ^^' thnks resolved